# Database table structure and logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario. I have a property table having many fields including property size.
so if some property have size 5 so in property table it will show 5 but If a user think that its size is not 5 but its 6. so i want to handle that that user save its size to 6 but not change original value that is 5. Also if that users get that property record it will show 6 size for that user but for all other users it will show 5 size.

Can any one help me how to handle this scenario in table structure or in displaying values user specific.? My database is in sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines, if the users are identifiable down at the database level:

You create you usual table plus a table containing user customizations:

```
create table dbo.T (
    ID varchar(19) not null primary key,
    PropertySize int not null
)
go
create table dbo.T_User (
    ID varchar(19) not null,
    [User] sysname not null,
    PropertySize int null
)
```

You then create a view through which all interactions should now occur, instead of the table:

```
create view dbo.V
with schemabinding
as
    select
        t.ID,
        ISNULL(u.PropertySize,t.PropertySize) as PropertySize
    from
        dbo.T t
            left join
        dbo.T_User u
            on
                t.ID = u.ID and
                u.[User] = SUSER_NAME()
```

And then a couple of triggers to make sure things are appropriately maintained:

```
create trigger T_V_I on dbo.V instead of insert
as
    insert into dbo.T (ID,PropertySize) select ID,PropertySize from inserted
go
create trigger T_V_U on dbo.V instead of update
as
    merge into dbo.T_User u
    using inserted s
    on u.ID = s.ID
    when matched then update set PropertySize= s.PropertySize
    when not matched then insert (ID,[User],PropertySize) values (s.ID,SUSER_NAME(),s.PropertySize);
```

So basically, each users customizations are stored as separate rows and the base table contains the "default" value that users will see unless they've applied a customization.

Depending on what authentication options are being used, [`SUSER_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187934.aspx) may not be the correct function but one of the other various `USER` functions will be.

Comment: Is this the only way or we can do it some other way instead of triggers?